# Headphone audio not working

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones

I have a 2014 MacBook Air running Mojave. Just today the audio stopped working through my headphones (through the headphone jack, not Bluetooth). I checked settings to see if there was anything wrong there, but everything's in order and it's recognizing that there are headphones plugged in. My headphones are working fine with my phone, and the speakers on my computer work too.